# Парсинг XML из 1С в PHP

Tags: php, xml, парсер, 1с

Подскажите пожалуйста как в php обработать xml из 1С сохраненную при обмене с сайтом(на русском...). Примеров куча в интернете, но у меня получается что при обработке c помощью simplexml_load_file между уровнями добавляются SimpleXMLElement Object, плюс доп. уровни появляются и весь xml текст на выходе становится не читабельным ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

вот простой пример

```
<?php
    //OPEN
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("import.xml");
    //READ
     foreach($xml->Каталог->Товары->Товар as $item){

            echo "ID: ".$item->Ид.'<br>';
            echo "NAME: ".$item->Наименование.'<br>';
            echo "ARTICULE: ".$item->Артикул.'<br>';
            echo "<br>";
        }

    ?>
```